# Finding base vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to find base vectors of such a subspace given by the following equation:

$W=\{[x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4] \in\mathbb{R}^4 : 2x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4=0 \}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$W= \text{span} \bigg\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
  1  \\
  0 \\
  0 \\
 2 
 \end{pmatrix} ,
\begin{pmatrix}
  0  \\
  1 \\
  0 \\
 1 
 \end{pmatrix} ,
\begin{pmatrix}
  0  \\
  0 \\
 1 \\
 -1 
 \end{pmatrix} 
\bigg\} $.
Since these $3$ vectors are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^4$ (easy to check), they form a basis for $W$.